# What is the name of the default schema in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, schema, oracle-sql-developer

When you create an object in Oracle, and do not specify a schema (object prefix), is there a name for that default schema?  I see in Oracle SQL Developer, that a newly created object shows up in the root object nodes when no prefix is specified, rather than the schema object nodes.

Creating table under schema X:

X.table_1

Creating table under default schema:

table_1

Comment: It's the current user's schema (= the name of the current user)

Comment: The object will be created in the schema of whatever user you are logged in as at the time.  Oracle's concept of "schema" is a bit different than other databases like, say, SQL Server.  A database user has exactly 1 schema that has the same name as the user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, it is the user you used to log in, and you can query it as below:

```
select sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') from dual;
```

You can change your current schema in your session however:

```
alter session set current_schema=USER2;
```

If you create a table after this, without specifying the schema, that table will be created in the USER2 schema regardless of what user you logged on with.